# Disabling excel Select Sheet dialog box using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am automating update link operation in excel using c#.But if any of the linked sheets is missing,I'm a getting a "Select Sheet" dialogue box.How to suppress this message and force selection of "Cancel" in that dialogue box.

```
  for (int iLinkCount = 1; iLinkCount <= astrLinks.Length; iLinkCount++)
     { 
      m_xlWorkBook.UpdateLink(astrLinks.GetValue(iLinkCount),XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
     }
```

[Select sheet pop-up image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnQXZ.png)

Comment: Have you tried `SuppressAlerts` in the Excel Object Model? xlApp.Supress... True then set it back to False;

Comment: I have tried xlApp.Application.DisplayAlerts=False; But it is not working.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Same problem.  Tried `objWorkbook.UpdateLinks = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlUpdateLinks.xlUpdateLinksNever` but does not help.